# What is the difference in meaning between output and result?

Tags: word-difference

Let's say that we ran an analysis (e.g. statistical analysis). What is the difference in meaning between:

> The **result** of this statistical analysis
>
> The **output** of this statistical analysis

When can I use 'result' and when I can use 'output'?
What is correct synonym to "result" to be used?

Comment: You mean outcome or output ? **output** is usually used for physical locations on devices such as an AC output, a usb output, and so on

Comment: No I mean output

Comment: "result" is much more better. "Output" does not seem a good choice in this case. Check here http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/output

Comment: What is the correct synonym to "result" to be used?

Comment: I found a very long list of synonyms to result. but I am not sure which one is correct to preserve the meaning of the previous example.

Comment: Outcome seems better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it this way: The *output* is the raw data that was generated by the statistical analysis. This is the information generated by the process before it has been considered and evaluated by the person or people who will make a decision.

The *result* is the decision made (or direction that you are going to take) based on your interpretation of the data.

So I see the *output* being the information generated by the computer, and the *result* being the decision made based on the output, or the impact the output had.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful. Result and output are slippery and depend a lot on context.

The result of the statistical analysis was that we all packed up work and went to the pub

The output of the statistical analysis is represented in the table below

Generally, an action yields a *result* in the form of an *output*. So the result from the statistical analysis would typically be an output in the form of a dataset.

However, the further study of that data (another action) yielded a result in the form of a decision to go to the pub. That makes it seem like the decision is a result in itself when actually it is a subsequent output.

No matter how complex or how simple, all calculations tend to follow the same path:

> input --> action --> result --> output

So, in your example:

```
    Data       Analysis       Raw data        Dataset  
          -->            -->           -->
   (Input)     (Action)       (Result)        (Output)
```

Feeds in to

```
   Datasets    Analysis       Conclusion      Decision  
          -->            -->           -->
   (Input)     (Action)       (Result)        (Output)
```

So, if the world was run by mathematicians and information scientists, that would be the end of it, everything is linked and nested iterations of that pattern. Sadly, it's not :) and English comes along and confuses things by often using the two terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Bad or good is the output, no matter good or bad that’s the implication of what we do.
Result is a pre-determined output, that’s why more controllable. The degree of good is higher than bad supposed to be.
Outcome is the impact of both output and/or result